# Given a matrix $A$ with a known Jordan decomposition, what is the Jordan decomposition of $A^2+A+I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So far, I understand that I have to look at each Jordan block. How do I prove that for a Jordan block with a value of x, $J_n(x)$, the Jordan decomposition of $(J_n(x))^2$ is $J_n(x^2)$ ? I have a feeling this will lead me to the solution. Thanks for your time.

Comment: It's not true that $(J_n(x))^2 = J_n(x^2)$. The left-side isn't even a Jordan block.

Comment: You're correct. I meant the Jordan form of the left side is equal to the right side.

Comment: It's more clear now, but your conjecture still isn't true. Take $$J(0) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ Then $J(0^2) = J(0)$, while the Jordan form of $(J(0))^2$ is just the zero matrix.

Comment: That makes sense. The question I'm looking at has non-zero Jordan blocks, this could be why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is a summary of a theorem (Theorem 1.36) from the book `Functions of Matrices: Theory and Computation` by Nicholas J.Higham.

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ complex matrix and $f(\lambda)$ be any polynomial.
Let's say $A$ has a Jordan block of size $r$ assoicated with eigenvalue $\lambda$.
We have

1. If $f'(\lambda) \ne 0$, then $f(A)$ has a corresponding Jordan block of same size $r$.
2. If $f'(\lambda) = f''(\lambda) = \cdots f^{(\ell-1)}(\lambda) = 0$ but $f^{(\ell)}(\lambda) \ne 0$ where $\ell \ge 2$, then

   - if $\ell \ge r$, the Jordan block of $A$ splits into $r$ copies of $1 \times 1$ Jordan block for $f(A)$ associated with eigenvalue $f(\lambda)$.
   - if $\ell \le r-1$, the Jordan block of $A$ splits into following Jordan blocks for $f(A)$:

     1. $\ell - q$ Jordan blocks of size $p$.
     2. $q$ Jordan blocks of size $p+1$.

     where $r = \ell p+ q$ with $0 \le q \le \ell=1, p > 0$.

The book has a proof for this. Since I don't know this stuff, I'm not going to copy it here.

**Update**

For example, take $f(\lambda) = \lambda^2 + \lambda + 1$. Since $f'(\lambda) = 2\lambda+1$. This means for any Jordan block $J_n(x)$ with $x \ne -\frac12$, $J_n(x)^2 + J_n(x) + I_n$ will be
similar to the Jordan block $J_n( x^2 + x + 1 )$.

A Jordan block $J_n(x)$ (or any matrix similar to it) is characterized by two properties.

- $J_n(x) - x I_n$ is nilpotent of order $n$.
- There exists a single vector $v$ such that
  $$v,\;J_n(x) v,\;J_n(x)^2 v,\;\ldots,\;J_n(x)^{n-1} v$$
  span the whole vector space.

When $f'(x) \ne 0$, one can show following list of vectors from same $v$
$$v,\;f(J_n(x)) v,\;f(J_n(x))^2 v,\;\ldots,\;f(J_n(x))^{n-1} v$$
span the whole vector space. That's why when $f'(x) \ne 0$, $f(J_n(x))$ will be similar to $J_n(f(x))$. I don't know the full details, but Higham's book will definitely cover that.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer, but I must admit I can't figure out how $f$ ties into this.