# A matrix $A$ is given with a known Jordan decomposition, what is the Jordan decomposition of $A^2+A+I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

This is a duplicate of a question I've already asked, but got no answer to. I would appreciated any help.

[Given a matrix $A$ with a known Jordan decomposition, what is the Jordan decomposition of $A^2+A+I$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666579/given-a-matrix-a-with-a-known-jordan-decomposition-what-is-the-jordan-decompo)

Comment: Note that you should use math markup also in the title!

Comment: So you shouldn't ask it again. You have asked the question some hours ago; people here is *not* at your service, do you know?

Comment: I'm sorry if it's in bad taste I just hoped more people would see it at this time.

Comment: You can consider starting a bounty on the previous question to put some additional motivation for people if it is so important.